# How to configure Django app on AWS elastic beanstalk without "Invalid HTTP_HOST header" errors

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Goal: To deploy an application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk but constantly receiving the error `ERROR 2023-06-16 17:54:37,903 exception 92295 139827093698112 Invalid HTTP_HOST header [some IP address]` despite several attempts.

Current status:

- The site works perfectly on my localhost.
- The `requirements.txt` file is in the same directory as `manage.py`.
- All changes are committed to the `git` `main` before deployment to Elastic Beanstalk (EB).
- There is no `.ebignore` file, only a `.gitignore` file.
- The `wsgi.py` file is located one level under `manage.py`, at `config>wsgi.py`. This is implemented in the `.ebextensions>django.config` file as shown below:

  ```
  option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
      WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application
  ```
- Two `settings.py` files are used: `base.py` and `production.py`. Following an existing Stack Overflow response, the `production.py` file is obtained from `django-cookie-cutter` and shown below:
  The production.py file:

  ```
  from .base import *  # noqa
  from .base import env
  import os

  SECRET_KEY = env("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

  if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
      DATABASES = {
          'default': {
              'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
              'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
              'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
              'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
              'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
              'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
          }
      }

  # SECURITY
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header
  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect
  SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT", default=True)
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure
  SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure
  CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#ssl-https
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-seconds
  # TODO: set this to 60 seconds first and then to 518400 once you prove the former works
  SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-include-subdomains
  SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS", default=True)
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-preload
  SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD", default=True)
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#x-content-type-options-nosniff
  SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF", default=True)

  def is_ec2_linux():
      """Detect if we are running on an EC2 Linux Instance
         See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/identify_ec2_instances.html
      """
      if os.path.isfile("/sys/hypervisor/uuid"):
          with open("/sys/hypervisor/uuid") as f:
              uuid = f.read()
              return uuid.startswith("ec2")
      return False


  def get_linux_ec2_private_ip():
      """Get the private IP Address of the machine if running on an EC2 linux server"""
      from urllib.request import urlopen
      if not is_ec2_linux():
          return None
      try:
          response = urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4')
          return response.read().decode("utf-8")
      except:
          return None
      finally:
          if response:
              response.close()

  private_ip = get_linux_ec2_private_ip()
  if private_ip:
      ALLOWED_HOSTS += [private_ip, 'your-django-env.elasticbeanstalk.com']


  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS", default=["prod-env-2.eba-cs4xedyt.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"])
  ```

The base.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path

import environ

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent
# gaingeeks/
APPS_DIR = BASE_DIR / "gaingeeks"
env = environ.Env()

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool("DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE", default=False)
if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    # OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
    env.read_env(str(BASE_DIR / ".env"))

# GENERAL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = env.bool("DJANGO_DEBUG", False)
# Local time zone. Choices are
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# though not all of them may be available with every OS.
# In Windows, this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = "Australia/Sydney"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths
LOCALE_PATHS = [str(BASE_DIR / "locale")]

# DATABASES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db(
        "DATABASE_URL",
        default="postgres:///gaingeeks",
    ),
}
DATABASES["default"]["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

# URLS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf
ROOT_URLCONF = "config.urls"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application
WSGI_APPLICATION = "config.wsgi.application"

# APPS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # "django.contrib.humanize", # Handy template tags
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.forms",
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    "gaingeeks.users",
    "gaingeeks.exercises",
    # Your stuff: custom apps go here
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# MIGRATIONS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#migration-modules
MIGRATION_MODULES = {"sites": "gaingeeks.contrib.sites.migrations"}

# AUTHENTICATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#authentication-backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "users:redirect"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url
LOGIN_URL = "account_login"

# PASSWORDS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#password-hashers
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher",
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"},
]

# MIDDLEWARE
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR / "staticfiles")
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(APPS_DIR / "static")]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

# MEDIA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR / "media")
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# TEMPLATES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#dirs
        "DIRS": [str(APPS_DIR / "templates")],
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#app-dirs
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "gaingeeks.users.context_processors.allauth_settings",
            ],
        },
    }
]

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#form-renderer
FORM_RENDERER = "django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting"

# http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#template-packs
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

# FIXTURES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#fixture-dirs
FIXTURE_DIRS = (str(APPS_DIR / "fixtures"),)

# SECURITY
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-httponly
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#x-frame-options
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"

# EMAIL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = env(
    "DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND",
    default="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend",
)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-timeout
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 5

# ADMIN
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Django Admin URL.
ADMIN_URL = "admin/"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
ADMINS = [("""Rob Menon""", "robertmenon95@gmail.com")]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# LOGGING
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logging
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose",
        }
    },
    "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console"]},
}


# django-allauth
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool("DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "gaingeeks.users.adapters.AccountAdapter"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {"signup": "gaingeeks.users.forms.UserSignupForm"}
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "gaingeeks.users.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter"
# https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {"signup": "gaingeeks.users.forms.UserSocialSignupForm"}


# Your stuff...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# from django extensions package to visualise the db schema:
GRAPH_MODELS = {
    "all_applications": True,
    "group_models": True,
}
```

- The following environment variables were set in the Elastic Beanstalk management console:

  ```
  ALLOWED_HOSTS 
  DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS
  DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
  PYTHONPATH   # set by AWS upon application creation
  RDS_DB_NAME
  RDS_HOSTNAME
  RDS_PASSWORD
  RDS_PORT
  RDS_USERNAME
  ```

Comment: Is the `private_ip` value the IP address you see in the log? It looks like, in production.py, you are setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS += [private_ip, ...]` but then overwriting it at the end of the file? `ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list(...`

Comment: You're right, I've shifted the code so I'm no longer overwriting ```ALLOWED_HOSTS``` and just adding to this instead. However error remains. Log errors are taking this format:

```2023/06/16 04:56:49 [error] 82680#82680: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.45.75, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.47.105"```